# React on button click Add textarea

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm making a simple resume portal and I have a `textarea(1)`, in which user can write his/her work experience. To add more than one work experience I have set a `button(Add)` which basically will add a new textarea(similar to `textarea(1)` but without `label`) just below the `textarea(1)` and so on. This all should be done when `button(Add)` is clicked.

If I am able to add my code in a `child component` that would solve my problem I think.

Here's below what I tried:

**Child component ( src -> Routes -> UserForm -> Components -> UserDetails -> index.js )**

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

 const UserDetails = () => {
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className='UserDetails'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <div className='persnlInfo'>
                            <h4>
                                Personal Information
                            </h4>
                            <p>Your Name</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Contact</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Address</p>
                            <textarea className='formAddress' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p id='impLinks'>Important Links</p>
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Instagram</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Linkedin</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <h4>
                            Professional Information
                        </h4>
                        <p>Objective</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        <p>Work Experience</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        <div className='addButton'>
                            <input type='button' id='addWrkExp' value='Add' />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default UserDetails;
```

**Parent component ( src -> Routes -> UserForm -> index.js )**

```
import React from 'react'
import Pages from '../../Components/HOC/Page/index'
import UserDetails from '../UserForm/Components/UserDetails/index'

    class UserForm extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return(
                    <>
                        <Pages 
                          showHeader
                          showFooter
                          >
                            <UserDetails />
                        </Pages>
                    </>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default UserForm;
```

Output:

[image]

To obtain the said above, I've searched up on this but not getting What and Where to put logic/code exactly. If I'm not wrong this can be done using `state` , `props` , `onClick()` and/or something related.

I hope this is enough from my side to understand the problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use a useState for the number of textareas on your page and then when button(add) gets clicked, that state gets increased by one

Comment: @Alixsep do you have some sharable code/demo for the same. That will be more helpful for me as I'm new to programming. If so, kindly share.

Comment: sure, hold up till I write one...

Comment: Alixsep, I'm done with for what I posted. I need some more help explicitly. Now in last, I've a button namely 'Generate CV' which I want to use(onClick) for displaying the entered input(s) as a CV on the same or on the very next page. For the same, how should I proceed? If you are available, kindly assist. I hope I'm clear with my query.

Comment: Alixsep, hope you will be going good. If you are available please answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859166/react-get-user-info-input-values-on-a-button-click/67860278#67860278

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useState for the number of textareas on your page and then when button(add) gets clicked, that state gets increased by one,

This is your Child component ( src -> Routes -> UserForm -> Components -> UserDetails -> index.js )

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const UserDetails = () => {
    const [ workXPs, setWorkXPs ] = useState(1);
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className='UserDetails'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <div className='persnlInfo'>
                            <h4>
                                Personal Information
                            </h4>
                            <p>Your Name</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Contact</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Address</p>
                            <textarea className='formAddress' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p id='impLinks'>Important Links</p>
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Instagram</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Linkedin</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <h4>
                            Professional Information
                        </h4>
                        <p>Objective</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        <p>Work Experience</p>
                        {[...Array(workXPs).keys()].map((workXP, i) => {
                            return <textarea key={i} className='formObjective' rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />;
                        })}
                        <div className='addButton'>
                            <input type='button' id='addWrkExp' value='Add' onClick={() => setWorkXPs(prev => (prev + 1))} />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default UserDetails;
```

if you wanna do more advanced and add remove buttons, check this: https://www.educative.io/blog/react-hooks-tutorial-todo-list

hope this helps

Comment: @Alixsep your state is an array so you can't write  () => setWorkXPs(prev => (prev + 1))

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import Pages from "../../Components/HOC/Page/index";
import UserDetails from "../UserForm/Components/UserDetails/index";

class UserForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textAreas: [{ text: "" }]
  };

  addTextArea = () => {
    let updatedTextArea = [...this.state.textAreas];
    updatedTextArea.push({ text: "" });
    this.setState({ textAreas: updatedTextArea });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Pages showHeader showFooter>
          <UserDetails textAreas={this.state.textAreas} clicked={this.addTextArea} /> 
        </Pages>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

i changed `<UserDetails textAreas={textAreas} clicked={this.addTextArea} />`  to `<UserDetails textAreas={this.state.textAreas} clicked={this.addTextArea} />`
in the UserForm component

child Component

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

 const UserDetails = (props) => {
    const {textAreas, clicked} = props
    return (
        <>
            <div className='UserDetails'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <div className='persnlInfo'>
                            <h4>
                                Personal Information
                            </h4>
                            <p>Your Name</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Contact</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Address</p>
                            <textarea className='formAddress' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p id='impLinks'>Important Links</p>
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Instagram</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Linkedin</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <h4>
                            Professional Information
                        </h4>
                        <p>Objective</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="5" 
                        cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        <p>Work Experience</p>
                        {textAreas.map(item => (
                        <textarea className='formObjective' value= 
                         {item.value} rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter 
                         here" />

                          )) }
                            <div className='addButton' onClick={clicked}>
                            <input type='button' id='addWrkExp' value='Add' />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default UserDetails;
```

Comment: Amir, Compile error: 'textAreas' is not defined in 'src\Routes\UserForm\index.js'. I think when 'UserDetails' is imported in 'UserForm' this error shouldn't occur. Am I right or not?

Comment: Amit, this worked fine. Should I use 'pull' instead of 'push' if I set a 'Remove' button adjoining 'Add' button for removing a textarea(but not the 1st one i.e. minimum one should remain on form). I mean rest of code will remain same except changing naming conventions and 'pull' from 'push'.

Comment: & lastly, I want to display the whole entered details on the very next page/screen by clicking on 'Generate CV' button(which is to be added yet). To get the same, what will be the logic/code? I hope you won't mind in assisting me one more time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use pull but i wouldn't do that if i were you. i will update my code for delete as well

Comment: @soloLearner do you want to have only one button to delete ? if so then in this case i'm guessing when we click on the delete button we delete the last text area, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233375/discussion-between-amir-hossein-and-sololearner).

Comment: Amir, I'm seeking to set one button for 'Adding' and one for 'Deleting' textarea. But I tried with another approach my first textarea is also getting deleted which I don't want. I'm trying to apply check over there for not deleting a textarea when left 1 in a form or on a screen.

Comment: add an if block and check if the length of textareas array is more 1 and then inside the if block add your deleting code like this `if (this.state.textAreas.length > 1) { delete related codes goes here })`

Comment: are you using react-router for handling the routes ?

Comment: both 'Add' and 'Remove' buttons perfectly set and working fine. Now I want to display all the data(entered by user) on onClick of 'Generate CV' button. How should I proceed Amir? If you are available kindly assist.

Comment: i think the best way is to use redux for that because you use react router so when you change the route data in the redux won't change

Comment: Amir, hope you will be going good. If you are available please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859166/react-get-user-info-input-values-on-a-button-click/67860278#67860278

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a state and change the state on the button click.
Then change the style according to the state.