# React Get User Info.(Input Values) On a Button Click

Tags: reactjs

I've made a simple resume portal. What I want is to get all the inputs values displayed on a screen on submit. This all should be done when `button(Generate CV)` is clicked.

Here's my code below:

**Child component ( src -> Routes -> UserForm -> Components -> UserDetails -> index.js )**

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const UserDetails = (props) => {
    const { wrkExpTxtArea, AcQuTxtArea, clickToAdd, clickToRmv, addAcQuTxtArea, rmvAcQuTxtArea, inputChangeHandler } = props
    return (
        <>
            <div className='UserDetails'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <div className='persnlInfo'>
                            <h4>
                                Personal Information
                            </h4>
                            <p>Your Name</p>
                            <input onChange={() => inputChangeHandler('name')} type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Contact</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Your Address</p>
                            <textarea className='formAddress' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p id='impLinks'>Important Links</p>
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Instagram</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                            <p>Linkedin</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <h4>
                            Professional Information
                        </h4>
                        <p>Objective</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />

                        <p>Work Experience</p>
                        {wrkExpTxtArea.map(item => (
                            <textarea className='formWrkExp' value={item.value} rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        ))}
                        <div className='Button' >
                            <input type='button' value='Add' onClick={clickToAdd} />
                            <input type='button' value='Remove' onClick={clickToRmv} />
                        </div>
                        
                        <p id='AcQu'>Academic Qualification</p>
                        {AcQuTxtArea.map(item => (
                            <textarea className='formAcQu' value={item.value} rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" />
                        ))}
                        <div className='Button' >
                            <input type='button' value='Add' onClick={addAcQuTxtArea} />
                            <input type='button' value='Remove' onClick={rmvAcQuTxtArea} />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Row>
                        <div className='sbmtButton'>
                            <input type='button' value='Generate CV' />
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default UserDetails;
```

**Parent component ( src -> Routes -> UserForm -> index.js )**

```
import React from "react";
import Pages from "../../Components/HOC/Page/index";
import UserDetails from "../UserForm/Components/UserDetails/index";

class UserForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    wrkExpTxtArea: [{ text: "" }],
    AcQuTxtArea: [{ text: "" }],
    inputValues: [{name: 'name', value: ''}],
  };
  inputChangeHandler = (e,inputName) => {
  let updatedInputs = [...this.state.inputValues]
  let changedInputValuesIndex = updatedInputs.findIndex(input => input.name === inputName) 
  if (changedInputValuesIndex > -1) {
  let updatedInputValue = 
  {...updatedInputs[changedInputValuesIndex]}
  updatedInputValue.value = e.target.value
  updatedInputs[changedInputValuesIndex] = updatedInputValue
  }
  this.setState({inputValues: updatedInputs})

  }
  addTextArea = () => {
    let updatedTextArea = [...this.state.wrkExpTxtArea];
    updatedTextArea.push({ text: "" });
    this.setState({ wrkExpTxtArea: updatedTextArea });
  };
  rmvTextArea = () => {
    let updatedTextArea = [...this.state.wrkExpTxtArea];
    if (updatedTextArea.length > 1) {
      updatedTextArea.pop({ text: "" });
    }
    this.setState({ wrkExpTxtArea: updatedTextArea });
  };
  addAcQuTextArea = () => {
    let updatedTextArea = [...this.state.AcQuTxtArea];
    updatedTextArea.push({ text: "" });
    this.setState({ AcQuTxtArea: updatedTextArea });
  };
  rmvAcQuTextArea = () => {
    let updatedTextArea = [...this.state.AcQuTxtArea];
    if (updatedTextArea.length > 1) {
      updatedTextArea.pop({ text: "" });
    }
    this.setState({ AcQuTxtArea: updatedTextArea });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Pages showHeader showFooter>
          <UserDetails inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler} wrkExpTxtArea={this.state.wrkExpTxtArea} clickToAdd={this.addTextArea} clickToRmv={this.rmvTextArea} 
          AcQuTxtArea={this.state.AcQuTxtArea} addAcQuTxtArea={this.addAcQuTextArea} rmvAcQuTxtArea={this.rmvAcQuTextArea} />
        </Pages>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Output:

[image]

I'm new to programming and getting values of user inputs seems insanely complicated to me. I'm little aware that this can be achieved using `state` , `props` etc. But I really have no idea about Where and What code is to place. I need help. That’s it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook and give a reference to each of `input` element.
For Example

```js
const name = useRef();


const handleSubmit = () => { 

    if(name.current && name.current.value){
        console.log(name.current.value) // input element's value
    }

}

return (<div>

    <input type="text" ref={name} />
   
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}> Submit </button>

</div>)
```

Comment: Shreyas, do you have any idea of getting this done using 'state'(in Parent component) and 'props'(in Child component)? If yes, kindly assist with the same.

Comment: ah yes, just create a object as state in parent component and pass the setter function down. you can use on change on input element to update the data in parent. let me know if this helps.

Comment: i tried but failed. I'm not getting which piece of code of is placed at what? could you please do this for me?

Comment: Can you provide me the files? Maybe email shreyasjadhav444@gmail.com or codesandbox.

Comment: Shreyas, I'll send it to your email in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I emailed you. A Zipped folder (containing all files) will be accessible through Google Drive. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

add an onChange prop to the input tag like this:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
const inputChangeHandler = (e) => {
   // e argument has received by default from onChange    
   const newValue = e.target.value
   setInputValue(newValue)

}
<input onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
```

whenever you start changing the value of the input, inputChangeHandler function will trigger and then update your state

Comment: Amir, as I understood that you want me to set 'onChange prop' in every input field in a child component. But what about parent component? I mean setting state and function before render() in a parent component. I hope I'm clear. Or could you please write whole code like you did yesterday before.

Comment: i did change your question code check that out

Comment: Amir, I tried updated code but nothing worked. Error is 'inputValues' and 'inputChangeHandler' is not defined in src\Routes\UserForm\index.js  Apart, I think you skipped to set 'onclick' attribute of 'Generate CV' button in a child component.

Comment: no the code only gives you the value of the inputs when you write them so you have values inside the parent component also the error is because i forgot to add this to the functions i will fix it

Comment: also i only added name input you can add the rest yourself like i did

Comment: alright Amir, To be true I messed up with the stuff in a Parent component. Might be because there's already some complicated stuff(for me) of button 'Add' and button 'Remove'. So with all that it seems tough to me to set new code of displaying whole inputs on Onclick of 'Generate CV' button. Can you do the whole work once for me? I mean I want you please to write the whole stuff required for 'Generate CV' button in both child and parent component to get done this task. I hope you won't mind in doing   this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Amir, I was guessing the same as you wrote of adding in rest of input fields. 2ndly, did you fix the error i.e. adding to functions?

Comment: okay Amir, once all value of the inputs are inside the parent component, what's after that? Do we then trigger Onclick event or not? I mean this is all where I'm getting confused and stucking around:(

Comment: what do you want to happen exactly ?

Comment: Amir, this is like a input form where an end user will fill his/her details to a generate a CV. Once he/she is done and clicks on 'Generate CV' button, his/her information should be shown on the same page or on the very next page.

Comment: I've gone through an article(HTML & JS) where it was suggested to design a CV template except form where the whole information will be placed and seen when button is clicked. Is it required in my case too?

Comment: Amir, it's 8 PM here at my side and it's my time to leave office. I'll join back tomorrow @ 9:30 AM. Hope to get in touch with you then. Thanks for everything. In last,  I would request you to consider my plea. TC

Comment: Amir, are you there?

Comment: Amir, hope you'll be going good. I'm trying to do my task since then but failing every time. I again request you to please assist me like before. My objective is to display entire information of user's input(s) when clicked on 'Generate CV' button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Pages from "../../Components/HOC/Page/index";
import UserDetails from "../UserForm/Components/UserDetails/index";

const initialData = {
  name: '',
  contact: '',
  address: '',
  facebook: '',
  instagram: '',
  linkedin: '',
  objective: '',
  workExperience: [],
  academicQualification: [],
}

const UserForm = () => {

  // holds all the form data from child component "UserDetails"
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialData)

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // submit handler
    alert(JSON.stringify(formData, undefined, 4))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Pages showHeader showFooter>
        <UserDetails form={formData} setter={setFormData} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      </Pages>
    </>
  )
}

export default UserForm;
```

UserDetails

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const UserDetails = ({ form, setter, onSubmit }) => {


    const hanldeOnChange = (e) => {
        setter(prev => {
            // access property by input element's name
            // update the state on parent component
            prev[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
            return { ...prev } // return copy after updating
        })
    }

    const [listTypeElements, setListTypeElements] = useState({ workExperience: '', academicQualification: '' })
    const handleListInput = (property) => {
        setter(prev => {
            prev[property].push(listTypeElements[property]);
            return { ...prev }
        })
        setListTypeElements(prev => {
            prev[property] = ''
            return { ...prev }
        })
    }


    const handleRemoveItem = (property) => {
        setter(prev => {
            prev[property].pop();
            return { ...prev }
        })
    }


    return (
        <>
            <div className='UserDetails'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <div className='persnlInfo'>
                            <h4>
                                Personal Information
                            </h4>
                            <p>Your Name</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='name' />
                            <p>Your Contact</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='contact' />
                            <p>Your Address</p>
                            <textarea className='formAddress' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='address' />
                            <p id='impLinks'>Important Links</p>
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='facebook' />
                            <p>Instagram</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='instagram' />
                            <p>Linkedin</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='linkedin' />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <h4>
                            Professional Information
                        </h4>
                        <p>Objective</p>
                        <textarea className='formObjective' rows="5" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={hanldeOnChange} name='objective' />

                        <p>Work Experience</p>
                        {form.workExperience.map((value) =>
                            <textarea className='formWrkExp' value={value} rows="3" cols="10" disabled={true} />)}

                        <textarea className='formWrkExp' value={listTypeElements['workExperience']} rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={(e) => setListTypeElements(prev => {
                            prev['workExperience'] = e.target.value;
                            return { ...prev }
                        })} />
                        < div className='Button' >
                            <input type='button' value='Add' onClick={() => handleListInput('workExperience')} />
                            <input type='button' value='Remove' onClick={() => handleRemoveItem('workExperience')} />
                        </div>

                        <p id='AcQu'>Academic Qualification</p>

                        {form.academicQualification.map((value) =>
                            <textarea className='formAcQu' value={value} rows="3" cols="10" disabled={true} />)}

                        <textarea className='formAcQu' value={listTypeElements['academicQualification']} rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Enter here" onChange={(e) => setListTypeElements(prev => {
                            prev['academicQualification'] = e.target.value;
                            return { ...prev }
                        })} />
                        < div className='Button' >
                            <input type='button' value='Add' onClick={() => handleListInput('academicQualification')} />
                            <input type='button' value='Remove' onClick={() => handleRemoveItem('academicQualification')} />
                        </div>



                    </Col>
                    <Row>
                        <div className='sbmtButton'>
                            <input type='button' value='Generate CV' onClick={onSubmit} />
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default UserDetails;
```

Comment: shreyas, why index.js is different from parent component? any specific reason?? I mean can't we set 'initialData' after or before 'state' and 'UserForm' function before render()

Comment: It's just the same. I'm using Functional Component which is newer version of class component. If you want you can convert back to class component too. Both are same.

Comment: class component file is already there, the need is just to fit the code appropriately in that I think. I'm trying to do the same but not getting success. sometime I get 'syntax error' sometime 'file not defined', sometime 'compile error' etc. etc. So can you please settle it down in both files? both files are in the body of a question and shared with you as well. Shreyas, my mean is not to bother you again and again but I'm really not getting this done by myself. I hope You understand my situation.

Comment: hey man i'm really busy with some project. it's not a big deal even if you use functional component instead of class component. why even you would you use class component anymore? you have to write so much more code with that. with functional you can simple finish it in one line with hooks. seems like you are new to react aren't you. you can refer https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class if you still wish to use class component.

Comment: yes shreyas, I'm new to react. I try my best to do with the same as you suggested.  Anyway, I'm really thankful to you for everything. TC and stay safe.